# MySQL: how to keep a synchronized copy of some tables on same server

Tags: mysql

I have a database table of 2 TB size
I want to keep a synchronized copy of that table as a second Table. Optimally it would synchronize both ways but one way would be acceptable too.

Making a simple copy is no solution, the table is being changed at 100mb/second. I need a true synchronization.

The best I found so far is a replication Setup using two MySQL instances on same machine but that’s way too complicated. Also would be a punch on memory.

I look for an elegant way that can be introduced to a system that can’t afford a downtime of more than a few minutes.

—

The reason why I do this is performance.
I use amazon EBS and that’s really slow. I want to keep a few database tables synchronized on instance nvme storage. Those should be very fast to access.
It would need to be restarted from zero when the server reboots.

Comment: you can use mysql `drbd` realtime replication for syncing.(2 machine active/passive cluster)

Comment: Doesn't really help Riad. drbd would require to recreate 6 TB of data, a huge downtime. drdb has very poor performance on such large loads. it would also require to replicate all the data, not just single tables which is too much and way too expensive.
same with mysql replication, I need it on the same server. replication on the same server would be quite a hack.